# Can't read .dat or .bin file in Ubuntu "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c++, ubuntu

So, I just started using Ubuntu recently.
I'm building this very simple program that will let me store some data and read back from it later on.

Using C++, fstream, some objects are stored in .dat file.

```
// function to store
void storeRecord(Record r){
     fstream afile;
     afile.open("file.dat" , ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
     afile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&r), sizeof(r) );
     afile.close();
}
```

But when I try to  (call *query()* function) read from the same file, I'm getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
void query(){
        Record r;
        fstream afile;
        afile.open("file.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
        while(afile.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&r), sizeof(r))){
             // do something
        }
        afile.close();
}
```

This used to work on windows. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Record{
public:
    // Constructors
    Record();
    Record(string accountID, string name, string deptID, string password,           int role);
    ~Record();

    // Assessors and Mutators
    string getAccountID();
    string getName();
    string getDeptID();
    string getPW();
    int getRole();

    void setAccountID(string accountID);
    void setName(string name);
    void setDeptID(string deptID);
    void setPW(string PW);
    void setRole(int role);

    // Other functions
    string toString();

private:
    string accountID;
    string name;
    string deptID;
    string password;
    int role;       // normal user, HR personal, admin
};
```

Comment: There is no r in query defined. What is Record? If it isn't a POD you have your bug.

Comment: There is. In the actual program. My mistake here. oops

Comment: What is the type of `Record` ? Does it have some [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), or some (even indrect or internal) pointer? **Your code  has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** so you are lucky that it crashes on Linux (and *unlucky* that it "appears" to work on Windows)....

Comment: BTW, I recommend against using binary data files. If you need them, spend weeks to specify well their [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format). Prefer something like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) and or textual format using [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it and give some [MCVE]. Currently it is not one (because `Record` is undefined)

Comment: It is part of my assignment's requirements to use binary file. So I don't really have a choice. Not that I know how to use other formats anyway.
Record is a user defined 'class'.

Comment: When does the segfault occur? At file open, file read, do stuff, or file close?

Comment: It occurs when reading

Answer (score 1):

Your `Record`  contains `std::string`  fields.

A `string` certainly contains pointers, and could contain some internal data with virtual functions (so having a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which is a hidden pointer); then that data has pointers. And a `string` is *not* a [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure) (but a fixed array of `char` would be, e.g. a field like `char name[48];` ....).

So your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so you are lucky that it [crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) on Linux (and *unlucky* that it "appears" to work on Windows)... BTW, when it is *apparently* "running" (e.g. on your Windows) the file format stays "undefined" and you won't be able to read again a data file written by an older version of your program (or even the same source compiled by an older or different compiler and C++ standard library).

Linux has [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization); that might explain why you've got a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). BTW, I guess that Linux might not crash if you write and read the same data file in the *same* [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (which is not particularly useful to you).

To understand more, you'll have to dive into implementation details, and you don't want to.

Apparently, you are required to implement some [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) machinery. Then specify first (and in details) your [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) (byte by byte, [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and "word size" matter and your file format should be "independent" of them), perhaps using some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation. Then implement the serialization routines, starting from elementary [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure) types. Or use some serialization library. Your file format and code should be portable (e.g. the same program on Raspberry Pi and on Linux/PC should be able to exchange data files).

BTW, I prefer much using some textual format, perhaps using [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/) (or XML). Or consider also libraries like [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) or [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/). In your case, your `Record`s map easily to rows in SQLite tables, or to JSON objects. Perhaps you should ask your teacher if you are allowed to use them....